# How Should I Parallelize My Genetic Algorithm Fitness Evaluation?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have a GA code that I developed myself. Since I'm new to coding, my code is not fast. I have a Dual-Core CPU 2.6GHz.
The only line of the code that takes a long time to run is the fitness function. I am not familiar with the GA toolbox and my fitness function is quite complex so I assume even if I knew how to use the GA toolbox, I would have to code the fitness function myself.
The algoritm's structure is as follows:
after generating the initial generation and evaluating the fitness values (which takes long but does not matter that much because this is only run once), it starts a loop which will be iterated for up to 10000 times. In each iteration, we have a new generation whose fitness values needs to be calculated. So when a new generation of 50 individuals is generated, the whole generation is fed to the fitness_function. In this function there is a for loop which calculates the fitness value for each 50 individual (so the for loop is iterated 50 times). Here is my question. How should I use parfor so that 25 individual is evaluated by one CPU core and the other 25 individuals with the other core, so that the calculation time is decreased to almost half. I already know from here

I have tried changing the for loop in the fitness_function directly to parfor and I have received the following error: "The PARFOR loop cannot run due to the way variable "Z" is used." and "Variable z is indexed in different ways. Potentially causing dependencies between iterations." Variable Z is a 50*3 matrix which stores the fitness values for each of the individuals.

Comment: Without seeing the code of your `parfor` loop, it's not possible to say exactly what's wrong. There are various constraints on the way that you are allowed to assign to variables within a `parfor` loop, and the error you're receiving indicates that you're hitting one of those. This page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html might help.

Comment: @Edric Actually I just need some explanation or description on where I should put the parfor loop and which parts should be run in the parallel manner as I described the steps of my algorithm. When I tried using the parfor loop, I didn't even specify anything about how I want to run the fitness function for 25 individuals with one core and the rest with the other core. 

I edited the question and added fitness function code. it seems that Z's classification is causing a problem but I don't understand why. I would be really grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: @Edric I tried using parfor on only the third block of loops that starts with defining "A" (which takes the longest to run) and ran the code without any errors. The pool started fine and the number of workers is 2. However, the running time was not reduced. So the code didn't get faster. Then, I activated the other CPU core from the System Configuration window and restarted the windows and ran the code again, now the number of workers is 1 and the code is even slower than before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your assignment into `Z` is that you have three different assignment statements, and that is not allowed. You need to make the assignment into `Z` meet the requirements for a ["sliced" variable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/sliced-variable.html). The easiest way to do this is to make a temporary variable `Zrow` to store the values for the `i`th row of `Z`, and then make a single assignment, like this

```
parfor i = 1:50
    Zrow = zeros(1, 3); % allocate to ensure parfor knows this is a temporary
    ...
    Zrow(1) = TTT;
    ...
    Zrow(2) = sum(FSL,1);
    Zrow(3) = 0.5*Z(i,1)+0.5*Z(i,2);
    % Finally, make a single sliced assignment into Z
    Z(i, :) = Zrow;
end
```

Also, in general, it's best to have the `parfor` loop be the outermost one. Also, whether `parfor` actually gives you any speed-up depends a lot on whether the body of the loop is already being multithreaded by MATLAB's built-in multithreaded capabilities. (If it is, then `parfor` using only your local machine cannot make things faster because in that case, the multithreaded code is already taking full advantage of your computer's resources).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the explanation. It worked. I just have one more question. How should I control the number of workers? Should I even activate extra processors from MsConfig setting or does MATLAB handle these things by itself?

Comment: By default, MATLAB uses as many workers as you have _physical_ cores on your system. This is almost always the best choice. If you want to change things, see here https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/discover-clusters-and-use-cluster-profiles.html#mw_7bc8fc7d-5daf-4268-be4d-7f77d6ef545e